# ViewPager, getChildFragmentManager() & getFragmentManager()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-nested-fragment

I'm developing an android app, with `TabHost` & `FragmentActivity` in each tab.

In my first tab I initialize a fragment with a `ViewPager` indicator and a button,
this button open a dialog with another `ViewPager` indicator, but my problem is the `ViewPager` in the fragment root activity is clashing with the `ViewPager`'s dialog.

In the root activity I'm calling `getChildFragmentManager()`... and is OK
but in the dialog `ViewPager` I'm calling again `getChildFragmentManager` but not working...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think the dialog is independent from the fragments so try getFragmentManager() or if you are using support library use getSuportingFragmentManager()